# install MobileFirst 7.0 server (for test and production environment) with IBM Installation Manager

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

While I'm following the [IBM Knowledge Center' guide](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_installing_wl_server_new.html?lang=en) to install a IBM MobileFirst 7.0 Server for production environment but that document is too simple for any newbees to handle it.

Can someone provide a more detailed guide and a MF 7.0 server download link so that I can use it as the local repository. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only IBM Customers and Business Partners can download the server components.
These components can be download from either the IBM Passport Advantage website or the IBM Fix Central website.

1. Download IBM Installation Manager
2. Download the GM version of the release you'd like to install
3. Download the latest iFix version of the release you'd like to install
4. Download the latest supported version of WebSphere Full profile or WebSphere Liberty profile or Tomcat for the release you'd like to install
5. Use the IBM Installation Manager to install the above components (4, 2 and 3 in that order)

   - In the IBM Installation Manager go to File > Repositories and add them (consult the documentation how)
6. Start with installing WebSphere
7. Use again the IBM Installation Manager to install ontop of the previously installed application server (Tomcat, WebSphere or Liberty) the MobileFirst Server components; you will be going through a wizard

   This step is not containable here as it varies and depends a lot on what you intend to use. Review the documentation.

Comment: can you give a detailed explaination of step 3 `iFix` and is it necessary? And is it necessary to install Was or Liberty (We have Tomcat 7.0)?

Comment: Yes, installing the iFix is required, unless you want to use a buggy version and then ask for support, which they will first tell you to install an iFix. You can use Tomcat as well.

Comment: so choose Tomcat, step 4,6 and 7 are not necessary, right?

Comment: All steps apply, doesn't matter what is your application server of choice.

Comment: So step 7 WebSphere is used for the Application Center? I dont think it's a must.

Comment: So think "Tomcat" instead of "WebSphere". I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Adar Sorry to bother but another question : Do I have to install MobileFirst Studio on the Linux Server first? (We already have build apps ,war files, wlapp files) .That means this Linux Server PC is just for publising and testing now, and we won't do any developing on it.